# Trouble downloading most recent version of my package from pip

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I recently started out using pypi for some packaging of a few tools that are useful in my everyday life, but I'm having trouble actually making sure that I can download the most recent version of my package.

The package in question is `pyfuzz` and I just upgraded to version `0.1.1`, but for some reason when I pip install it, even with the `--upgrade` flag I can only pull down `0.1.0`.

The file is clearly recognized on the pypi site (See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFuzz/0.1.1) and if I try to upload again I get an error saying that I've already uploaded 0.1.1.

This is my setup file:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    name="PyFuzz",
    version="0.1.1",
    author="Slater Victoroff",
    author_email="Slater.R.Victoroff@gmail.com",
    packages=["pyfuzz"],
    url="http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFuzz/",
    license="LICENSE.txt",
    description="Simple fuzz testing for unit tests, i18n, and security",
    long_description=open("README.txt").read(),
    install_requires=[
        "lxml >= 2.3.2",
        "requests >= 1.2.3",
        "numpy >= 1.6.1",
        "cssselect >= 0.8"
    ],
)
```

And I uploaded using `python setup.py sdist upload` am I doing something silly here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the PyPi Index hasn't been updated yet:

https://pypi.python.org/simple/PyFuzz/

*(Output at time of writing)*:

```
PyFuzz-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

This is a known issue with PyPi - package indexes and mirrors for the actual packages are often out of sync, if not down alltogether. Usually its the other way round though - the index listing a version that some package mirrors don't have yet. http://www.pypi-mirrors.org/ may be useful to check mirror freshness.

So it's not a mistake on your side, but a failure of PyPi. Just wait, and eventually it should update and resolve itself.

What you can do in the meantime is to install the most recent version of your package by explicitely giving the URL to the source tarball:

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PyFuzz/PyFuzz-0.1.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: You're welcome. By now the index seems to have been updated, so installing should work normally again.