# What am I doing wrong pypi missing "Links for"

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I'm trying to tryout pypi to publish some libraries. So I started with a simple project.
I have the following setup.py:

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='event_amd',
    packages = ["event_amd"],
    description='Port for EventEmitter from nodejs',
    version='1.0.7',
    author="Borrey Kim",
    author_email="borrey@gmail.com",
    url="https://bitbucket.org/borreykim/event_amd",
    download_url="https://bitbucket.org/borreykim/event_amd/downloads/event_amd-1.0.6.tar.gz",
    keywords=['events'],
    long_description = """\                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    This is an initial step to port over EventEmitter of nodejs. This is done with the goal of having libraries that are cross platform so that cross communication is easier, and collected together.                                          
    """
)
```

I've registered it but: sudo pip install event_amd gives me an error:
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for event-amd
(I'm not sure how event_amd turns to event-amd?)
Also there is no links under (which other projects seem to have ):
https://pypi.python.org/simple/event_amd/

I was wondering if I am doing something wrong in the setup.py or what may be causing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that registration of your package with PyPi succeeded, but the index isn't updated yet. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108135/trouble-downloading-most-recent-version-of-my-package-from-pip/18108527#18108527) for example. Also, I'm currently getting a `503` for https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=event_amd&submit=search, so they seem to currently have some backend issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upload a source archive after registering the release: `python setup.py register sdist upload`